# Quicksort: Why moving pivot to the end?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, quicksort

Whats the motivation of first moving the chosen pivot element to the end of the array?
The only thing I can see is that when incrementing the lower index i , we dont need to check i < n but only a[i] < pivot.

Is that it?

Thakns

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivot is moved to the end of the array because it doesn't know where it will end up until the other elements are moved. In order to avoid constantly shifting the entire array's elements after each comparison, the pivot is placed at the end until the rest of the array is sorted (for that step of the quicksort), then placed in its correct location.  This means the array only needs to be shifted twice (once in the beginning, once at the end), instead of after each comparison.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "constantly shifting the entire arrays elements after each comparison", could you give an example? Like so if the pivot remains in the same place (eg its not moved to the end), then when you do the comparison, when would you have to shift?